# Decimal to octal transformation

Tags: decimal-expansion

```
52.8 div 8 = 6.6 mod 4.8
6 div 8 =0.75 mod 6
```

The result is 64.8 
Is that correct?
I'm quite confused with 4.8

Comment: $52\div 8$ is either $6.6$, or it is $6$ with remainder $4.8$. What you have is some mix of both.

Answer (score 0):

The integer part is $52_{10}=64_8$. The fractional part is computed by repeated multiplication by $8$ and working with integer and fractional part:

```
0.8 * 8 = 6.4   ->  next digit = 6
0.4 * 8 = 3.2   ->  next digit = 3
0.2 * 8 = 1.6   ->  next digit = 1
0.6 * 8 = 4.8   ->  next digit = 4
0.8 * 8 = 6.4   ->  next digit = 6  etc
```

so $52.8_{10} = 64.63146314631463146314631463146314_{8}\dots = 64.\overline{6314}_{8}$